# How to replace jmeter keys when running Taurus

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

### Problem:

I am currently hard coding a password in my jmeter .jmx test file.
I want to be able to either set this in the config.yaml or on the command line using something like a "-o modules.jmeter.properties" switch (to replace this in the CI pipeline)

However I cant get either of these to actually replace the value in the .jmx file.

I have looked through the [Taurus doco](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/) and ended up trying the following.

Updating the config.yaml file:

```
execution:
- executor: jmeter
  scenario:
   script: ../scripts/apigee_loadtesting.jmx
   data-sources:
    - ../datafiles/
 concurrency: 2
 ramp-up: 30s
 hold-for: 1m
 steps: 2

modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      es.password: P@ssw0rd!
```

Also tried this from the commandline:

```
bzt ../config.yaml -o modules.jmeter.path=/usr/local/apache-jmeter-4.0.2/bin/jmeter \
-o modules.jmeter.properties.espassword=P@ssw0rd! config.yaml
```

But neither of them seem to do anything meaning, Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You have an extra `.` in yaml property, should be `espassword`

Comment: Must of been an example typo. That still doesnt make any difference.

Comment: I take it that this switch should find :
    
    <stringProp name="Argument.name">espassword</stringProp>

And replace this: with the "P@ssw0rd!" 
    
    <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Taurus itself will not change anything in the .jmx script, just make sure that you refer the property using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(es.password,)}` in the .jmx script and the value will be substituted with the one from .jmx file or command-line override.
2. I would avoid using dots in properties names as it might cause problems with overriding properties values from the command-line. So stick to `espassword` everywhere if possible
3. The change your command line so `config.yaml` would be **the last** argument like:

   ```
   bzt -o modules.jmeter.path=/usr/local/apache-jmeter-4.0.2/bin/jmeter -o modules.jmeter.properties.espassword=P@ssw0rd! config.yaml
   ```

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more information on running JMeter tests using Taurus

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I can pass it in from the commandline. i do a similar thing with the thread, steps etc. Couldnt get it to work for this previously.
Cheers for the help

Comment: I'm running a performance test jenkins job configured using taurus. I have existing jmeter jmx file which i would like to run with this job. This jmx file is expected to read inputs from jenkins job inputs. So, i configured jmx file as said by @Dmitri T with $_P() for reading inputs, but still the values coming as empty during test run. Any help would be very much appreciated.